# How to prevent locking when parent table is updated whenever an insert/delete occurs in child table?

Tags: database, postgresql

I have a simple use case wherein I update the parent table when a row is inserted/deleted in the child table.

Suppose we have a **Products** table and **Items** table and **ProductId** is the foreign key in the **Items** table.

Whenever an item is inserted or deleted in the **Items** table, an update is made in the Products table corresponding to the item. An update is simply a query like:

```
UPDATE "Products" SET "PropertyX" = $1, "UpdatedAt" = $2 WHERE "Id" = $3
```

**Problem:**

If the items inserted/deleted in the items table correspond to the same product in the products table then the database load increases considerably causing timeouts even for 3K reqs/min due to **Lock:transactionid** waits.

I tested this on Aurora Postgres (with 4 CPUs, 16G Ram) and this happens even if the number of rows in the Items table is in the thousands and the number of rows in the Products table is in the hundreds. I used .net core with entity framework.

Comment: Do you have an index on `items(productid)`?

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: you should really avoid those dreaded quoted identifiers. They are much more trouble than they are worth it. https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_upper_case_table_or_column_names

Comment: Yes, indexes are added on all the foreign keys, and the query I shared is generated by Entity framework (orm). So quotes are added by the orm.

Comment: You can't update rows without locking them.  You need to either avoid the updates, or keep the transactions doing the update as short as possible.